# Firestore not sending link in its response to the client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a new firestore document. where I am also adding an image URL as a field. Its also getting stored in the firestore database. But when I am reading data on the client the image URL is not in firestore's response.
[Firestore Database Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAxXW.png)

[Code Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrADY.png)

Comment: Can you share some details like screenshot of your Firestore structure and your code ?

Comment: Added images link please check

Comment: The code you've shared seems to be updating a document. Can you share the code that you are using to read the document? This _"But when I am reading data on the client the image URL is not in firestore's response."_

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)